# Сравнение строк из двух файлов и вывод строки по частичному совпадению

Tags: python, match, строки

У меня есть два файла: один файл содержит пути, второй файл содержит имена объектов.

Первый файл содержит пути и выглядит так:

```
Project_name\SubProjectName1\Subname1\Subname2\Subname3\object_name1\
Project_name\SubProjectName1\Subname1\Subname2\Subname3\object_name2\
Project_name\SubProjectName1\Subname1\Subname2\Subname3\object_name3\
Project_name\SubProjectName1\Subname1\Subname2\Subname3\object_name4\
Project_name\SubProjectName2\Subname1\Subname2\Subname3\object_name5\
Project_name\SubProjectName2\Subname1\Subname2\Subname3\object_name6\
Project_name\SubProjectName2\Subname1\Subname2\Subname3\object_name7\
Project_name\SubProjectName2\Subname1\Subname2\Subname3\object_name8\
```

Второй файл содержит в себе нужные object_name

```
object_name1
object_name3
object_name5
object_name7
```

Мне нужно перебрать оба файла и вывести только те строки из первого файла с путями, в которых содержатся строки с object_name из второго файла.

Перебор через

```
    with open(path_file, 'r') as f1, open(object_file, 'r') as f2:
        for x, y in zip(f1, f2):
            f = open(test, 'a')
            f.write("{0}\n{1}\n".format(x.strip(), y.strip()))
```

не работает, т.к. zip перебирает по наименьшему количеству строк в файле и останавливается.

Найти совпадающие строки через

```
    data = open(path_file, 'r')
    for row in data:
        if object_data in row:
            n = open(test, 'a')
            n.write(row)
    data.close()
```

тоже не выходит, так файл object_name полностью является строкой.

Также пробовал разбивать оба файла на списки и искать совпадения.

Если разбивать `object_file.split('\n')` и `path_file.split('\n')`, то поиск по частичному совпадению не происходит.

Если разбивать `object_file.split('\\')` и `path_file.split('\\')`, то происходит только поиск совпавшего элемента.

Как можно сравнить оба эти файла построчно и вывести только нужные мне строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

решение с помощью регулярки (результат выводим в файл):

```
from re import search

with open(path_file) as f1, open(object_file) as f2, open(test,'a') as f3:
    pat = f2.read().replace('\n','|')
    for i in f1.readlines():
        if search(pat, i):
            f3.write(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот вывод совпадений:

```py
with open(path_file, "r") as f1, open(object_file, "r") as f2:
    confirmed_paths = []
    paths = f1.readlines()
    objects = f2.readlines()

    for path in paths:
        for object_name in objects:
            if object_name.strip() in path.strip():
                confirmed_paths.append(path)
                break

print(confirmed_paths)
```